# How do crossfade 3 pngs keeping background transparent so I can put it on a background video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, transparency

I'm trying to take 3 PNG images with transparent background and make a crossfade video with them so I can then put that video on to a background video.  I understand I can do possibly do this in 1 command but would like to keep it separate as the background video may be interchangeable.  What I have so far is;

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.png -loop 1 -t 1 -i 2.png -loop 1 -t 1 -i 3.png -
filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-
(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; [2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*
(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; [0:v][b1v][1:v]
[b2v][2:v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

This seems to work but the background is now black not transparent, I have tried making the output different file types (avi, mov etc.) but that has no effect. The next command I am running is;

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1080:-2[fg1]; 
[1:v]scale=1920:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bg];[bg]
[fg1]overlay=400:400:shortest=1,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -movflags 
+faststart final.mp4
```

This also seems to work but again the video I am overlaying doesn't have the transparency so looks bad.  Is there a way I can make the first video honour the transparency from the original pngs?  If it requires a single command I am happy to do that but I've hit a wall at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first command, change `format=yuv420p` to `format=yuva420p`. Transparency requires an alpha channel but you are, at, present, converting to a format without one. `format=yuva444p` will provide a slightly better quality.

And more importantly, output to `-map "[v]" -c:v png out.mov`